# How to make devx asp:grid responsive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I am using dx:ASPxGridView (Version-11.1) to show grid with Questions and having 3 options [(1)Yes or mostly yes. (2)Mid or undecided (3)No or mostly no] to choose for their respective questions. We already achieved the desktop view (please refer to attached image) but we want to make it responsive (as shown in attached image) when the page goes to mobile view.
Below is grid code for original desktop view.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdQuestionnaire" OnCustomColumnDisplayText="grdQuestionnaire_CustomColumnDisplayText" EnableCallBacks="false" ClientInstanceName="grdQuestionnaire" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                KeyFieldName="QuestionID" OnHtmlRowCreated="ASPxGridView1_HtmlRowCreated" Width="100%">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="NO" VisibleIndex="0">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  Caption="Question" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1">
                                        <DataItemTemplate>
                    Are you by nature a forgiving persion?
                   </DataItemTemplate>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  Caption="Yes or mostly yes" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2">
                                        <DataItemTemplate>
                    </DataItemTemplate>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  Caption="Mid or undecided" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3">
                                        <DataItemTemplate>
                    </DataItemTemplate>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  Caption="No or mostly no" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4">
                                        <DataItemTemplate>
                    </DataItemTemplate>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <Columns>
                 </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using suggestions from [this demo](https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Adaptivity/ResponsiveLayout.aspx), and which screen size you want to try with responsive layout?

Comment: Yes i tried it using <Settingsadaptivity> property, but it doesn't work saying 'This is not supported element'. And i am trying to make for screen size "576x768".